# Suddenly having sql_error_code = 42601 STATEMENT: SET statement_timeout TO ? in logs

Tags: postgresql, heroku

So no scripts were running at this point and no where in our app are we setting a timeout. Started happening 2 hours ago, any clue/idea on why/how this happened? Also checked heroku status and no luck either

> [AMBER] [10-1] sql_error_code = 42601 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "?" at character 26
>
> [AMBER] [10-2]  sql_error_code = 42601 STATEMENT: SET statement_timeout TO ?

Answer (score 0):

We also saw these errors, across all our apps, from 7:19 to 9:45 am.  It seems most likely to be a Heroku thing, although the Heroku status page has not yet reported anything, but then again, it's not an outage so it might never.